# Calculations using Pandas apply & lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column for dates (YYYY/MM/DD format) and one for wind speed measurements.  Each date has more than one wind speed measurement associated with it, and I want to calculate the standard error of wind speed measurements on each day.

I use the pandas 'groupby' to group all of the wind speeds to the date they were taken on, and I calculate the mean and number of measurements taken from each day.

To calculate the standard error, have to sum the squared difference of each value from a day and the average of values from that day.  Obviously, these are different lengths, and I cannot figure out how to do this with the lambdas function.

Is there a better way to go about this?

```
#calculate daily averages, daily number of measurements, and list of every value from day
average_from_date = df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].mean()
number = df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].count()
values_from_date = df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].apply(list)

#return list of standard errors for each date in the data set
standard_errors = df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].apply(lambda x: (sum((values_from_date - 
average_from_date)**2)/(number-1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the [groupby.GroupBy.sem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sem.html) is a good way to calculate this since it is a ready function in pandas, there might be cases when you need to calculate a new column with a function that does not exist in the library.

#### apply() + lambda

This is how you would calculate a new column* using the "apply lambda" approach:

```py
res1 = df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].apply(lambda x: ((x-np.mean(x))**2)/(len(x)-1))
```

What is important to understand that since `df.groupby(['time'])` is DataFrame(GroupBy) object the `df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms']` is a Series(GroupBy) object and the `apply()` function therefore is [pd.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).  It takes a function as an argument, and the function will be called with the pandas series (here: the `df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms']`)  as the argument. Now, you know already how to calculate the standard deviation if you get a list/Series.

#### apply() + another function

With apply you are not restricted to lambdas, but the argument can be any function that takes `pd.Series` as the argument. So, equally good solution would be.

```py
def calculate_std(x):
    ave = np.mean(x)
    return ((x-ave)**2)/(len(x)-1)

res2 = df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].apply(calculate_std)
```

With a little more complex calculations this is *much more readable and preferable solution*.

#### How fast are different alternatives?

One might think that "using lambdas is faster", but if you time the functions yourself you see that there is no speed gains from using lambdas:

```py
In [3]: timeit df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].apply(lambda x: ((x-np.mean(x))**2)/(len(x)-1))
3.26 ms ± 358 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [4]: timeit df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].apply(calculate_std)
2.87 ms ± 63.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

On the other hand, the `sem` function mentioned by [oli5679](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4520420/oli5679) is faster

```py
In [5]: timeit df.groupby(['time'])['wind_spd_ms'].sem()
1.33 ms ± 40.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

*(Altough, library funtions are not always the fastest. For example, using `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift` for shifting..)*

---

* This is the equation for groupwise *standard deviation* (not standard error of groupwise mean)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas groupby has a 'sem', which you can use without having to create your own lambda function. See more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sem.html).

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'val':[1,100,-40,5,7,8]})

test.groupby(['group'])['val'].sem()
#a    41.554516
#b     0.881917
```

See below example of how to do it from scratch. I think original attempt wasn't quite fitting definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error). You to divide total squared difference from mean by N-1 to calculate sample variance, but also need to divide this by N, and squareroot to get SEM.

```
test["squared_difference_from_average"] = (
    test["val"] - test.groupby(["group"])["val"].transform("mean")
) ** 2

group_count = test.groupby(["group"])["val"].count()

standard_errors = (
    (
        (test.groupby(["group"]) ["squared_difference_from_average"].sum())
        / (group_count - 1)
    )
    / group_count
) ** 0.5
```